# Using LINQ and contains with comma separated values

Tags: c#, linq, contains

I am trying to get multiple values from a LINQ query using contains. In `Contains` condition, I want to pass comma-delimited values like, I wonder if it is possible, here is the code

```cs
UnitQuery = UnitQuery.Where(x => x.ParcelBase.Code.Contains("'3800105', '38001014'")
                    || x.Unit.UnitParcels.Any(y => y.ParcelBase.Code.Contains("'3800105','38001014'"))
                    || x.EUnit.EUnitNumber.Contains("'3800105','38001014'"));
```

This code treats comma delimited string as a single value, I am looking for multiple values out of this LINQ.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you are doing in your code

```
object_data_member.Contains(list_of_valid_values)
```

this is what you should be doing

```
list_of_valid_values.Contains(object_data_member)
```

Concretely...

```
string[] parcelBaseCode = new string[] {"3800105", "38001014"};

UnitQuery = UnitQuery.Where(x => parcelBaseCode.Contains(x.ParcelBase.Code)) ...
```

etc.

Comment: One suggestion, `parcelBaseCode` should be a `HashSet<string>`. The OP only gave two items in the list so performance is probably negligible, but if this was just an example (or if anyone runs into this answer), large lists that you check this way should be a `HashSet<T>`.

Comment: I have tried the suggested code it but it is not working, another suggestion?

Comment: See my updated response. If that still does not work for you, please edit your question to show your amended code, your input data, and the results you're obtaining.

Comment: Yes, it worked just fine , thank you so much.